# Правильно ли я понимаю, что делать навигацию по DOM-дереву в React нельзя?

Tags: reactjs

Правильно ли я понимаю, что в React не используется навигация по dom дереву: querySelector, closest и прочее? Если я хочу что-то получить по событию (например по клику), то я должен это передать исключительно в обработчике: `onClick={() => {addToCard(item.name, item.price)}}` ?

А если мне нужно прослушать событие на одной кнопке, а прочитать значение на другом конце странице, то я тоже должен это прокидывать через пропс?

Comment: Навигация по DOM конечно работать будет, но лучше записать эту идею в разряд вредительской, если от неё можно отказаться. Компонентная система специально разработана для того, чтобы напрямую не зависеть от других частей приложения и используемого кода, а так же эффективно перерисовывать DOM дерево при наличии изменений.

Answer (score 0):

Надо представить, на каком уровне абстракции мы работаем.
Есть модель и представление (view-model).
`addToCard` -- это какая-то операция, изменяющая модель.

Вариант 1:
Внутри addToCard мы про существование страницы не думаем,
а дополнительные данные уже есть в модели на момент клика.

Вариант 2:
Дополнительные данные идут в addToCard аргументом.
Тогда компоненты представления могут использовать общего предка, например с помощью `useContext`

Comment: Ну у меня есть два случая, где я дёргая DOM:
1) Это карточка товара - по клику я получаю имя товара и его цену;
2) Фильтр на чекбоксах - кликнули по фильтру - перебрал все чекбоксы и если он выбран - записываю в стейт

Comment: Я бы всё через стейт делал: 1) Если карточка рендерится реактом из стейта, то цена товара в стейте 8000000 прямо тут, а в доме "80 000,00 SEK" еще искать и парсить. 2) Тут более спорно. А если un-check в зависимости от другого фильтра, или подсказки какие-то выводить по ходу чеканья

Comment: Я просто делаю коворкинг, когда одновременно несколько человек с разных компов одну форму видят в процессе редактирования. Там не только в стейт, но и по сети надо постоянно.